# How to define a template class function with nested type of the template argument in its signature outside the class

Tags: c++, templates

I have a template class that requires from its template argument to have nested types. And it uses these types in its member function signatures. I found the following solution to declare the member functions:

```
template <class ElementType>
class AKL_API AklMemoryPool
{
public:
    typedef typename ElementType::DataType DataType;
    typedef typename ElementType::RetrieveType RetrieveType;
...
    RetrieveType Retrieve(unsigned int offset) const;
    DataType* EstablishCUDA();
    DataType* WriteToCUDA();
    DataType* ReadFromCUDA();
    DataType* GetCUDA();
...
};
```

But I can define the functions only inside the class declaration.
If I try to define it outside like:

```
template <class ElementType>
AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::RetrieveType AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::Retrieve(unsigned int offset) const
{
...
}
```

I get compile errors.

And here is the problem because I need to hide the implementation as it produces compile errors if is visible from some places. I use the AklMemoryPool class only as a base class so I decided to move the implementation to cpp file and include it in cpp files of inherited classes.

So here is a question:
How to define these functions outside the class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use `typename`

```
template <class ElementType>
typename AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::RetrieveType
AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::Retrieve(unsigned int offset) const
{
...
}
```

or use the type in a *correct* context (since C++11)

```
template <class ElementType>
auto
AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::Retrieve(unsigned int offset) const
-> RetrieveType
{
...
}
```

Comment: I forgot about the C++11 stuff :D +1

Answer (score 3):

You have to use the `typename`keyword before `AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::RetrieveType`, like this:

```
template <class ElementType>
typename AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::RetrieveType AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::Retrieve(unsigned int offset) const
{
    //...
}
```

You'll can see how this compiles [here](http://ideone.com/kKmdSt).

Answer (score 2):

You need `typename`:

```
template <class ElementType>
typename AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::RetrieveType
^^^^^^^^
AklMemoryPool<ElementType>::Retrieve(unsigned int offset) const
{
    ...
}
```